# Como utilizar dos DLL's con el mismo namespace y el mismo nombre de clase en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

en esta ocasión necesito importar a un proyecto de VB dos DLL's que tienen el mismo namespace, el mismo nombre de clase y los mismos métodos pero son DLL's completamente distintas en cuanto a funcionalidad ya que una es más reciente que la otra (son DLL's para realizar facturación), la única diferencia que tienen actualmente es el nombre del archivo. Intente importarlas pero no me funcionan me marca que son ambiguas al tratar de mandar a llamar los métodos.

```
Imports libfacturacion
Imports libfacturacion_com
...
Dim x As New libfacturacion
Dim y As New libfacturacion_com
```

Despues de importarlas y declararlas en las variables como nueva instancia al tratar de acceder a los métodos me marca que son ambiguos. Por alguna extraña razón aunque están en variables diferentes no me respeta el acceso a los métodos.

Comment: En el app.config puedes indicar las versiones de las DLL's (siempre y cuando sean versiones distintas). Por si te sirve de ayuda.

Comment: Hola @HéctorJ.OrihuelaRuiz sin son versiones distintas de la DLL, pero con indicar que son versiones distintas se solucionaría el uso de las mismas en mi código al mandar a llamar los métodos?

Comment: Sinceramente no lo puedo asegurar, me topé con un problema similar hará un año y probé varias cosas, una de ellas lo que te he comentado, también probé a cambiarle el nombre a una de las dll's, y así... siento no poder ser más exacto, sinó lo habría posteado como respuesta y no como comentario jeje

Comment: Ok no te preocupes cualquier comentario es bienvenido, intentare con eso que comentas para ver si funciona

Comment: Hola, cómo distingues en tu código la versión del ensamblado que quieres usar en cada momento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede usar dos versiones en el mismo ejecutable siempre y cuando lo configures en el app.config o web.config (lo suyo es que estén los ensamblados y firmados, fijate en el atributo `publicKeyToken` del `assemblyIdentity` y establece los ensamblados en una subcarpeta de `bin` cada uno con su versión.

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Factura.API" publicKeyToken="12ab3cd4e5f6abcd"
                  culture="neutral" />
                <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="v1\Factura.API.dll" />
                <codeBase version="2.0.0.0" href="v2\Factura.API.v2.dll" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Luego deberías crearte dos `AppDomain` diferentes y cargar en cada uno de ellos la versión concreta. Para redirigir al ensamblado especificado (a través de la ruta completa) debes implementar una clase "proxy". Así puedes distinguir en tu código la versión que quieres usar en cada momento.

Un ejemplo puede ser

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim myAppDomainSetup As New AppDomainSetup()
        myAppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
        Dim myEvidence As Evidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence
        Dim myDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", myEvidence, myAppDomainSetup)
        Dim myDomain2 As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain2", myEvidence, myAppDomainSetup)

        Dim type As Type = GetType(Proxy)
        Dim proxy = DirectCast(myDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName), Proxy)


        Dim pathToDll = System.IO.Path.Combine(myAppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase, "v1\Factura.API.dll")
        Dim pathToDll2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(myAppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase, "v2\Factura.API.v2.dll")

        Dim assembly = proxy.GetAssembly(pathToDll)
        Dim assembly2 = proxy.GetAssembly(pathToDll2)

        Dim typeFacturacion1 As Type = assembly.GetType("Factura.API.Tipo1", True)
        Dim facturacion1 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeFacturacion1)

        Dim typeFacturacion2 As Type = assembly2.GetType("Factura.API.Tipo1", True)
        Dim facturacion2 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeFacturacion2)

        AppDomain.Unload(myDomain)
        AppDomain.Unload(myDomain2)

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub


End Module

Public Class Proxy
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject
    Public Function GetAssembly(assemblyPath As String) As Assembly
        Try
            Return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath)
        Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
            ' throw new InvalidOperationException(ex);
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo voy a revisar para implementarlo en mi proyecto

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta marcala como correcta

Answer (score 0):

En C# existe el concepto de *alias externo* para estas situaciones. En vb.net no deberias tener problemas con el `Imports`, usando este formato:

```
Imports NombreFicheroDll.Namespace.Clase
```

y luego debes definir una variable con la clase:

```
Dim Dll1 As New NombreFicheroDll.Namespace.Clase
Dll1.Metodo()
```

Comment: Esto ya lo intente pero cuando intento acceder a la clase en el imports no me la muestra